# QGIS Geometry Generator make_line using road network

Tags: network, road, nearest-neighbor, st-makeline

I want in QGIS 3.22 Geometry Generator to connect related points with a line, but the line must go between the points along the shortest network of paths.
I have two layers:

- one is "points" point type layer and every feature has 'name' and 'parent' field. The 'parent' field shows which point 'name' on the same layer the given point is related to.
- the second is a "roads" line type layer (brown) with a network of roads

this code generates a straight line

```
make_line( 
$geometry ,  
geometry( 
    get_feature( 'points', 'name' , 'Parent')
)
```

)

I want the given line to run along the shortest path on the road layer (brown) network.
The picture shows that the point is not located directly on the road, the algorithm must find the nearest road and connect it with a line. Something like this as code

```
closest_point( 
collect_geometries ( 
    overlay_nearest( 
        'roads', 
        $geometry
    )
),
$geometry
```

)

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use processing tools ... i want that the connection lines are changing dynamically if points are displaced.

Comment: If the network would consist of simple lines, then it would be easy to use `line_sunstring ()` and `line_locate_points()`, together with what you have (`closest_point()`) to achieve that. However, for a network layer consisting of mulitpart or several different layers, I don't see an easy solution as there are no network/routing functions in QGIS expressions.

Comment: Probably using a Virtual layer or PostGIS, this can be achieved

Comment: What do you mean "simple lines"? But what about simplifying the road network into more straight lines? I don't want to measure the distance along the road so much, but to more realistically visualize the connections between the points. Babel could you describe your idea in code, that would help me a lot!

Comment: Does the lines have some direction (one way) or it doesn't matter?

Comment: it dosent' matter ... the idea is to get best/shortest roads network between all points

Comment: As mentioned, I don't see a solution using QGIS expressions as they have no functions for network/routing (maybe creating custom functions would be a an approach, but for that, I would recommend to post another question). If the points you want to connect are on the same line (same feature), than as mentioned you could use `line_sunstring ()` and `line_locate_points()`, but for a answer, I would need to have more information about your data - best provide sample data (points and line as well as which points should be connected). Otherwise, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Easiest is still using processing tools, don't know why you don't want to use them. If you change your points, just run it again, maybe creating a model.

Comment: for training data take a completely arbitrary network of roads and place the points randomly between lines

Comment: I don't want to re-run processing tools after changes, as a result of which a new layer with data will be created and then I have to start re-associating the new layer with other related layers.